# Get confuse about NBA 2k16 ps3 version

Tags: ps3, nba2k16

I would like post here to seek to your adivce about nba 2k16 ps3 version please.

So far as I know nba 2k16 is the latest version and I plan to buy it for my little brother as a gift.

I read this website:
http://support.2k.com/hc/en-us/articles/210469848-What-Modes-Does-NBA-2K16-Contain-

I notice ps3 contains three game modes which are MyCAREER, MyTEAM and Online Quick Match.

So does that mean if I buy the ps3 version, my little brother can only play those 3 game modes?

Also, I am confuse about the trophies in nba 2k16.

What are those trophies used for? Should I have to buy them all for the game?

In addition, in those trophies, I see some trophies are related to MyGM or MyLegaue, for example, Cavs Magic, Changes A Comin' and Grass Is Greener. Here comes another question: if ps3 version only contains 3 game modes that exclude MyGM and MyLegaue, how can I buy or get those trophies for my little brother?

Although  the cover that contains 3 nba players seems cool, I see there are many covers. So what is the meaning of those covers, are they related to the game features?

I am sorry if I ask too many questions in this post but I really would like to confirm the features in nba 2k16 ps3 version before I buy it, because I don't want to disappoint my little brother and he loves playing nba video games.

I shall be grateful for your advice on this issue please. Thank you.

Comment: Im sorry, but we dont take multiple unrelated questions (eg. what game modes are there, what are trophies) in a single question. Ask each question, seperately, instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I answer this question myself.

Although I want to give my litter brother a surprise, I think I should let him know the features in NBA 2K16 ps3 version, I will show him this link http://support.2k.com/hc/en-us/articles/210469848-What-Modes-Does-NBA-2K16-Contain- and let him to consider whether he wants it or not.